# Rvest parse.response 404 error is breaking my for loop. How to keep looping?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have the following section of code nested within a `for` loop

```
mywebsite <- html(webstring)
cast <- html_nodes(mywebsite,".some-node")
text_of_cast<-html_text(cast)
```

The problem is that one of the URLs returns the following error:

> Error in parse.response(r, parser, encoding = encoding) :    client
>   error: (404) Not Found

And this error breaks my `for` loop because the page doesn't exist.

Is it possible to ignore this error and keep looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds that the "try" function from the base package is what you are looking for.